# Barman Backup failed issuing start backup command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

```
barman backup pg
$ barman list-server
pg - Backup PostgreSQL Database (via SSH)
---
$ barman check pg
Server pg:
        PostgreSQL: OK
        superuser or standard user with backup privileges: OK
        wal_level: OK
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
        backup minimum size: OK (0 B)
        wal maximum age: OK (no last_wal_maximum_age provided)
        wal size: OK (0 B)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 0 backups, expected at least 0)
        ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
        ssh output clean: FAILED (the configured ssh_command must not add anything to the remote command output)
        systemid coherence: OK (no system Id stored on disk)
        archive_mode: OK
        archive_command: OK
        continuous archiving: OK
        archiver errors: OK
```

when start backup it failed

```
$ barman backup pg
ERROR: Impossible to start the backup. Check the log for more details, or run 'barman check pg'
```

Answer (score 0):

**ssh output clean: FAILED (the configured ssh_command must not add anything to the remote command output)**

### *i solve this problem by disable output ssh from server postgres ,
then when i retry check configuration it success*

Server pg:
PostgreSQL: OK
superuser or standard user with backup privileges: OK
wal_level: OK
directories: OK
retention policy settings: OK
backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
backup minimum size: OK (166.2 MiB)
wal maximum age: OK (no last_wal_maximum_age provided)
wal size: OK (8.6 MiB)
compression settings: OK
failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 2 backups, expected at least 0)
ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
systemid coherence: OK
archive_mode: OK
archive_command: OK
continuous archiving: OK
archiver errors: OK